# Spark could not filter correctly?

Tags: serialization, apache-spark

I encounter an wired problem that the result is not correct.
I have a class called A, and it has a value called `keyword`.
I want to filter the RDD[A] if it has some `keyword`.

Spark environment: 
version: 1.3.1
execution env: yarn-client

Here is the code:

```
class A ...
case class C(words:Set[String] ) extends Serializable {

  def run(data:RDD[A])(implicit sc:SparkContext) ={
    data.collect{ case x:A=> x }.filter(y => words.contains(y.keyword)).foreach(println)
  }
}

   // in main function
  val data:RDD[A] = ....
  val c = C(Set("abc"))
  c.run(data)
```

The code above prints nothing. However if I collect RDD[A] to local, then it print something! E.g.

```
data.take(1000).collect{ case x:A=> x }.filter(y => words.contains(y.keyword)).foreach(println)}
```

How could this happen?

Let me ask another related question: Should I make `case class C` extends `Serializable`? I don't think it is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is quite easy. If you run the `println` function when you collect data locally, what happens is that your data are trasferred over the network to the machine you are using (let's call it the client of the Spark environment) and then it is printed on your console. SO far, everything behaves as expected. Instead, if you run the `println` function on a **distributed** `RDD`, the `println` function is executed locally on the worker machine on which there are your data. So the function is actually executed but you won't see any result on the console of your client, unless it is also a worker machine: in fact, everything is printed on the console of the respective worker node.

No, it's not necessary you make it `Serializable`, the only thing is serialized is your `words:Set[String]`.